# Alternative to deprecated `canvas.clipRect` with `Region.Op.REPLACE`?

Tags: android, canvas, clip

I have the following code:

```
 private RectF tmpRect = new RectF();

 public void drawClipedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, Polygon tmpPoly, int x, int y) {
    this.canvas.clipPath(getPath(tmpPoly));
    this.canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (float) x, (float) y, this.fillPaint);
    this.tmpRect.set(0.0f, 0.0f, (float) this.canvas.getWidth(), (float) this.canvas.getHeight());
    this.canvas.clipRect(this.tmpRect, Op.REPLACE);
}
```

But since Android SDK28 the implementation of clipRect was deprecated and dropped out.
I am trying for 4 hours to find a way to replace that method with something else, unsuccessful.

How do I achieve same result since clipRect is deprecated and not working anymore?

Comment: Not clear what `this.tmpRect()` is, but you can probably just use `Canvas.save()/restore()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found by myself:

```
public void drawClipedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, Polygon tmpPoly, int x, int y) {
        Path p = getPath(tmpPoly);
        Log.d("POINTS","POINTS: "+p);
        this.canvas.clipPath(getPath(tmpPoly));
        this.canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (float) x, (float) y, this.fillPaint);
        this.tmpRect.set(0.0f, 0.0f, (float) this.canvas.getWidth(), (float) this.canvas.getHeight());
        //this.canvas.clipRect(this.tmpRect, Op.REPLACE);
        this.canvas.save();
        float fWidth = (float)this.canvas.getWidth();
        float fHeight = (float)this.canvas.getHeight();
        //this.canvas.drawRect(0, 0, fWidth, fHeight, new Paint());
        this.canvas.clipRect(0.0f, 0.0f,  fWidth, fHeight);
        this.canvas.restore();
    }
```